# Sort by field values in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a MySQL table named **tbl_posts** with columns **title,category,timestamp**.

```
title  category  timestamp
CAT    animal    2014-12-12 05:54:49 
ROSE   flower    2014-12-12 05:54:50
APPLE  fruit     2014-12-12 05:54:51
DOG    animal    2014-12-12 05:54:52
```

I want a MySQL Query to sort according to category. **When I search for category 'animal', CAT and DOG wants to show first and after that append other categories too.** My desired output is as follows

```
   title  category  timestamp
    DOG    animal    2014-12-12 05:54:52
    CAT    animal    2014-12-12 05:54:49 
    ROSE   flower    2014-12-12 05:54:50
    APPLE  fruit     2014-12-12 05:54:51
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? Did you search around for similar questions?

Comment: First try querying yourself. Ask to others, only if you get stuck.

Comment: I tried ORDER BY etc and gets struck.That's Y im here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT y.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.category = x.category  
 ORDER 
    BY y.title = 'dog' DESC
     , y.category;
```

or something like that

Comment: Great work.. Works fine.. Thanks You Very Much

Answer (score 0):

This should be done by ORDER BY clause as below:

```
SELECT title, category, timestamp
FROM tbl_posts
ORDER BY category
```

Comment: When I search for category flower, I want to show all the results that comes under this category along with that I want to show results of other categories too.. Must show the search category first and append other categories next

Comment: Sorry that's another follow up question. I would say you raise another question on this forum by closing this one.

Comment: @almasshaikh No it isn't. This answer is incomplete.

Answer (score -1):

Ahem, query (based on what you shown) to obtain that result

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY category ASC, timestamp DESC
```

Comment: why the -1 downvoter?

Comment: I downvoted because this answer doesn't properly address the question. See my answer above for a solution that does (albeit rather inelegantly)